# Alternatives to slow DEL large key

Tags: redis

There is async UNLINK in the upcoming Redis 4, but until then, what are some good alternatives to implementing DELete of large set keys with no or minimal blocking?

Is RENAME to some unique name followed by EXPIRE 1 second a good solution? RENAME first so that the original key name becomes available for use. Freeing the memory right away is not of immediate concern, Redis can do async garbage collection when it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXPIRE` will not eliminate the delay, only delay it until the server actually expires the value (note that Redis uses an approximate expiration algorithm). Once the server gets to actually expiring the value, it will issue a `DEL` command that will block the server until the value is deleted.

If you are unable to use v4's `UNLINK`, the best way you could go about deleting a large set is by draining it incrementally. This can be easily accomplished with a server-side Lua script to reduce the bandwidth, such as this one:

```
local target = KEYS[1]
local count = tonumber(ARGV[1]) or 100
local reply = redis.call('SPOP', target, count)
if reply then
  return #reply
else
  return nil
end
```

To drain, call repeatedly the script above with the key-to-be-deleted's name, and with or without a count argument, until you get a `nill` Redis reply.

Comment: Thanks. Does Redis pick a time to expire and clean up values when it's less busy/loaded? I guess my main concern is blocking the client that needs to delete a key but does not care to wait for the cleanup, it wants to return quickly from the Redis call so it can proceed with other non-Redis work.

Comment: Will UNLINK in v4 improve on the delay, in other words will it happen truly async without blocking other clients that do not care about the key that is being cleaned up?

Comment: Wrt picking a good time - yes, but Redis doesn't take into consideration the time it will take to expire a value so a big value, even if the server is less busy, will still take the time to evict. Wrt to v4 async UNLINK, yes - freeing the memory is done w/o blocking, but the key is deleted from the database immediately.